# What is the scope of a standard function in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, var

I know there are different ways of declaring a function in JavaScript. Specifically my doubt is with the "standard" way of declaring a function, let's say we have the next function:

```
function salute(name) {
    let phrase = `Hello ${name}, nice to meet you`;
    document.write(phrase + `<br/>`);
}
```

(I know `document.write()` ain't a good practice, but I'm just using it to test code).

Now, it is possible to assign another function to `salute`, e.g.:

```
salute = function(){
    document.write(`This is a different function <br/>`);
}
```

Is the original `salute` function declare like a var variable/object? I know one can redeclare a variable within the same scope if declared as var, e.g.:

```
var aVariable = 10;
var aVariable = 11;
```

But this doesn't work with let and const as explained here:
[Difference between var and let](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var)

Continuing with the original code, I realized I can redeclare `salute` using var:

```
var salute = function(){
    document.write(`This is a different function <br/>`);
}
```

But I can't do the same with let or const. This made me conclude that the "standard" way of declaring a function has an implicit var scope. Am I right?

Comment: The second `salute` will likely overwrite the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This largely depends on what you consider "standard" to which I would say the answer is yes and no.

On the top level environment of a script, your function behaves like a variable declaration would (e.g. with `var`). That means you could write the same function declaration twice even and no error would be thrown out. The last declaration would override the previous one.

```
function test(){
    console.log(1);
}

function test(){
    console.log(2);
}
test(); //2
```

Inside a function definition, the behavior is pretty much the same:

```
(function nested(){
    function test(){
        console.log(1);
    }

    function test(){
        console.log(2);
    }
    test(); //2
})()
```

Notice this could even be `strict` code:

```
(function nested(){
    'use strict';
    function test(){
        console.log(1);
    }

    function test(){
        console.log(2);
    }
    test(); //2
})()
```

However, once we start using blocks AND `strict` code... things start to change...

```
'use strict';
{
    test();
    function test(){
        console.log(1);
    }

    function test(){
        console.log(2);
    } //SyntaxError
}
```

Also, unlike script top level environment, modules also behave like blocks on `strict` mode (as far function declaration goes).

```
function test(){
    console.log(1);
}

function test(){
    console.log(2);
}
test(); //SyntaxError
```

It's still not exactly as `let` since functions still get hoisted (`let` variables do not get initialized until they reach the declaration) and it's definitely not immutable as a `const` variable, since you could still overwrite the functions.

```
'use strict';
{
    test = function(){
        console.log(2);
    }
    test(); //2
    function test(){
        console.log(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, objects and functions are also variables. so functions could be considered automatically Global based on this website: https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp